# How can I get POI to interpret a large Excel cell as a long?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel spreadsheet that has one very large numeric column. I need to read it as a very large number (string) but excel displays it in scientific notation, and POI show it to me the same way. I have tried setting the data format to "0" or "General" which should preclude the conversion but it does not.

```
Cell input: 50222222222222222222 
Excel shows: 5.0222222222222197E+19
POI gets: 5.0222222222222197E+19
```

This is a serial number and must be exact.
I understand the problem is, a numeric field is read as a double. If I could somehow convert that to a long (and then to a string) I would be a happy coder. I don't care if the solution is to change the column format (which didn't work for me) or a java conversion.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the Cell as "Text"?

Comment: Prefix the number with a `'` as you enter it into the cell, to force Excel to store it as a String not a Number?

Comment: I have no control over the spreadsheet so I can't add the ' to the cell. I tried formatting it as a number, as "general" and as "text". When I do, the style shows the appropriate style but the celltype still says "numeric" and it wrong.

Comment: @Nexevis I just now tried to set the celltype to String. The value is still 5.0222222 etc

Comment: How does the cell input get into the cell? There something would must be changed. Once the cell value is 5.0222222222222197E+19 there is no more chance of getting 50222222222222222222.

Comment: @AxelRichter ~ I'm starting to see you are right. Looking at the raw row data in POI, it shows as nnnE+nn. If I re-open it in excel, the number value has trailing 00000.

Answer (score 0):

Further research gives the unobvious answer: you cannot.